# Problems with Library class and readWrite and clear methods

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I'm trying to finish my last school project where I'm setting up a application that deals with books, collections of books (we’ll call that a library), and the UI client for those classes.

I'm working on two methods that are giving me trouble: The **writeToFile** method which does file i/o functionality (read books from its data file, write books to the same data file)and the **clear** method, which clears an ArrayList called **allBooks**. The application itself has an interface called Citable, a class called **Book**. , a Library class which provides basic accessors (book count, book at a specified position), provide search and add/delete functionality (search by ISBN, add book with all details, delete book by ISBN)

The problem is that I'm trying to setup the two classes (**within the Library class**) so I can reuse code from the other two classes and I'm looking for ideas on how to make the code better (And honestly for a less fatigued coder to check my code) from experienced coders. This is what I've done so far:

The Citable Class (which is a interface):

```
/**
 * Write a description of interface Citable here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public interface Citable
{
    public String getISBN();
    public String getAuthor();
    public String getTitle();
    public String getPublisher();
    public int getPublicationYear();
    public int getMonth();
    public int getDay();
    public int getPageCount();
}
```

The Book Class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>, Citable
{
    String isbn, title, author, publisher;
    int publicationYear, month, day, pageCount; 
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book(String title, String isbn)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn  = isbn;
    }

    public String toString (){
        return isbn + "\n" + title + "\n" + author + "\n" + publisher + 
        "\n" + publicationYear + "\n" + month + "\n" + day;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book other) {
       return isbn.compareTo(other.isbn);
    }

    @Override
    public String getISBN() {
        return isbn;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPublisher(){
        return publisher;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPublicationYear(){
        return publicationYear;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }

    @Override

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    @Override

    public int getPageCount(){
        return pageCount;
    }

    //other methods from your interfaces here...
}
```

And the Library Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Library
{
    private ArrayList<Book> allBook = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Library(ArrayList<Book> other) {
    if (other == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("null pointer");
    } else
        allBook = other;
    }

    public int getCounter (int counter) {
        return counter;
    }

    public String findISBN (String isbn){
        return isbn;
    }
    public String deleteISBN (String isbn){
        return isbn;
    }
    public String findBook (String title){
        return title;
    }
    public boolean readWrite (File file){
        super.writeToFile(file);
        try {
            FileWriter outFileFW = new FileWriter(file, true);
            outFileFW.write(nextISBNIndex + "\r\n");
            for (int isbnIdx = 0; isbnIdx < nextIsbnIndex; isbnIdx++) {
                outFileFW.write(books[isbnIdx] + "\r\n");
            }
            outFileFW.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arraylist[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}

}
```

Any help would seriously appreciated.

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: Book and Citable compiles, but Library isn't due to the two problem methods

Comment: I think I've missed a import somewhere, but I'm not sure of my logic in readWrite and clear

Comment: Class Library has MANY problems. From wrong readWrite (lost data???, hard to understad), false method name, falsifing returns in most methods (few will be void)... not sure You understand constructor (I gues wrong form of copying constructot)... etc

Comment: U use 3 different names for books collection , it is copy & paste?

Comment: In the Book Class, I'm using Comparable and Citable (the interface), thus I don't understand constructor

Comment: Some of it, yes

Comment: More in Library than the others

Comment: construct of Book can be OK (to some degree - in school projekt). Bad is Library

Comment: SO is not compilation assist (BTW You dont give errors)

Comment: Totally detail: NullPointerException -> IllegalArgumentException  with good explanation

Comment: vote down because You hide information about compilation errors

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need library app. you can reconstruct your application to something like that:

```
public class Book{
private String title;
private String isbn;
//.... other properties of the book.

//constructors
//getters and setters
public String getTitle(){
     return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
     this.title= title;
}
//do the same for isbn
//overriding toString, equals and hash...

}

public class library{
   private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
   /* help methods like getCount which get size of books ArrayList, clear method 
    * which clears the books ArrayList, and other help methods you need.
    */
}
```

and in the main method you add books or delete and read&write to the data file.

Comment: Hmmm ... partial answer is correct SO answer? I think not

Comment: I won't give the whole code of his application. He should try. I just give him  a hint to reconstruct his application, because as you see he doesn't understand well the OOP.

Comment: You answer changes (almost) nothing. Class from big letter

Comment: Would you clear you comment? and You can give the correct SO answer instead of all theses comments on others.

Comment: impossible to give full anwser (code) with not clear assumptions. If author wants to learn, can realize partial corrections from comments. BTW Partially agree with You, SO is not assigments service

Comment: One extra question: How would one import variables from another class since setting some of the data in Books Class to private?

Comment: The encapsulation mechanism is to make variables are private and then make getters and setters methods public to access these variables from outside.